# POST Non English alphabets using REST API

Tags: c#, jira-rest-api

I am using JIRA REST API to create a new issue and there are some non english alphabets in the description and some other custom fields. 
The request JSON looks like

```
    {
      "fields": {
        "issuetype": {
          "id": 10303
        },
        "description": " Additional informations",
        "customfield_11419": "",
        "customfield_11413": "Editor: Øyst gården",
        "customfield_11436": {
          "value": "DONE"
        },
        "customfield_11439": "Jørund"
      }
    }
```

Once the HTTP POST is completed using the below code , i am getting an OK response back from endpoint.

```
            HttpWebRequest request;
            WebResponse response;         
            request = WebRequest.Create(jira_url) as HttpWebRequest;
            request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
            byte[] authBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes((jira_email + ":" + jira_token).ToCharArray());
            request.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(authBytes);
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(json_string)) //the inpot JSON string to be submitted 
            {
                request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf8";
                byte[] jsonPayloadByteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(json_string.ToCharArray());
                request.GetRequestStream().Write(jsonPayloadByteArray, 0, jsonPayloadByteArray.Length);
            }                
            response = request.GetResponse();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
            response_string = reader.ReadToEnd();
            reader.Dispose();
```

But while rendering the details in JIRA interface i can see that some ? replacing  the special non English characters .
Example

"Editor: Øyst gården" from JSON to

Editor: ?yst g?rden  in user interface

How can we avoid the ? and make sure the non English alphabets are getting posted to endpoint

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems you use wrong Encode/Decode type.

if you decide to use UTF-8, You won't be use ASCII

So Here,

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(json_string)) //the inpot JSON string to be submitted 
        {
            request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf8";
            byte[] jsonPayloadByteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(json_string.ToCharArray());
            request.GetRequestStream().Write(jsonPayloadByteArray, 0, jsonPayloadByteArray.Length);
        }
```

you need to change it as

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(json_string)) //the inpot JSON string to be submitted 
        {
            request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf8";
            byte[] jsonPayloadByteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json_string.ToCharArray());
            request.GetRequestStream().Write(jsonPayloadByteArray, 0, jsonPayloadByteArray.Length);
        }
```